# Question about definition of smooth maps in differentiable manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

I am following the [Nigel's differentiable manifolds lectures](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/%7Ejoyce/Nairobi2019/Hitchin-DifferentiableManifolds.pdf). In page 14 you can find the following definition:

> A map $F:M\to N$ of manifolds is a **smooth map** if for each point $x\in M$ and chart $(U_\alpha,\varphi_\alpha)$ in $M$ with $x\in U$ and chart $(V_i,\psi_i)$ in $N$ with $F(x)\in V_i$, the set $F^{-1}(V_i)$ is open and the composite function
> $$\psi_i\circ F\circ \varphi^{-1}_\alpha$$
> on $\varphi_\alpha(F^{-1}(V_i)\cap U_\alpha)$ is a $C^\infty$ function

**My question is:** Why he imposes that $F^{-1}(V)$ must be open? Many other autors only requires that $\psi_i\circ F\circ \varphi^{-1}_\alpha$ must be $C^\infty$ in $\varphi_\alpha(U)$

Comment: That's the hypothesis that $F$ is, to start with, a continuous map. Smoothness of maps on Euclidean space can, furthermore, only be checked on open sets.

Comment: It's been ages, but as I recall, my interpretation was to prevent two separate points on V from having a common pre-image point at the boundary; voiding the original definition of the forward function.  There was something more substantial about Compact covering consistency; I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the point is that, as Hitchin explains on p9, he is not assuming in the definition of a manifold that it is a topological space, unlike most authors. Instead he derives the topology from the definition. Hence on p14  he does not assume in Definition 6 that F is continuous. As a result he has to say explicitly that $F^{-1}(V_i)$ must be open. Other authors would assume F is continuous so it follows automatically that $F^{-1}(V_i)$ is open, as $V_i$ is open.